# PowerApps custom form- global variable seems cached

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-form, powerapps-forms

I have a PowerApps customized form. On that form I have some buttons. I want to be able to hide those buttons if someone is not in the FinanceMgrs list. I have set a global variable in the OnStart event of my App. The formula is:

Set(varIsAdmin,If(!IsBlank(LookUp(FinanceMgrs,Title=User().Email,Title)),true,false))

(I got the formula from one of Shane Young's videos - it works). What is happening, though, is that on the form, even if I remove myself from the FinanceMgrs list, it keeps on evaluating to true and showing the button. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, thanks for the response about refreshing my form. As it turned out, I was just screwing up the formula for the !IsBlank. The correct formula should have been

!IsBlank(Lookup(MyList,Title=User().Email,Title))

THAT evaluates to true or false. Which is what I needed.

Comment: Thank you for your sharing, you could mark you reply as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Set the **OnEdit** property of the SharePointIntegration control to following:

```
Refresh('YourSPList');   /* <-- add this formula */
ResetForm(SharePointForm1); /* <-- add this formula */
EditForm(SharePointForm1)
```

Set the **OnNew** property of the SharePointIntegration control to following:

```
Refresh('YourSPList');
ResetForm(SharePointForm1); /* <-- add this formula */
NewForm(SharePointForm1)
```

Set the **OnView** property of the SharePointIntegration control to following:

```
Refresh('YourSPList');
ResetForm(SharePointForm1); /* <-- add this formula */
ViewForm(SharePointForm1)
```

Then re-publish your custom form to your SP list, then check if the issue is solved.